# different RSA keys for git for the same remote host

Tags: git, rsa

I would like to use different rsa keys for the same host when connecting to different git repositories on this host.

For example I have 2 git repositories on example.com:

```
git@git.example.com:rep1
```

and

```
git@git.example.com:rep2
```

The typical method for using 2 different RSA keys is for different hosts
~/.ssh/config  :

```
Hostname example.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1
```

This does not work for me, since both repositories are hosted on the same host.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Host` keyword:

```
Host host1
HostName git.example.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Host host2
HostName git.example.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

And then use `ssh host1` or `ssh host2` instead of using full host name.

Comment: good advice, but I would indent all lines belonging to given `Host` definition to make it more clear

Comment: Thx for the answer, but how do I add my git remote now?

Comment: @NilsZiehn: Use `ssh://host1/rep1` and `ssh://host2/rep2` as URLs. (I changed the host identifiers to make it more readable).